# Reset increment in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I just started learning Postgres, and I'm trying to make an aggregation table that has the columns:

- user_id
- booking_sequence
- booking_created_time
- booking_paid_time
- booking_price_amount
- total_spent

All columns are provided, except for the `booking_sequence` column. I need to make a query that shows the first five flights of each user that has at least x purchases and has spent more than a certain amount of money, then sort it by the amount of money spent by the user, and then sort it by the booking sequence column.

I've tried :

```
select user_id,
       row_number() over(partition by user_id order by user_id) as booking_sequence,
       booking_created_time as booking_created_date,
       booking_price_amount,
       sum(booking_price_amount) as total_booking_price_amount
from fact_flight_sales 
group by user_id, booking_created_time, booking_price_amount 
having count(user_id) > 5
   and total_booking_price_amount > 1000
order by total_booking_price_amount;
```

I got 0 when I added `count(user_id) > 5`, and `total_booking_price_amount` is not found when I add the second condition in the `HAVING` clause.

**Edit:**
I managed to make the code function correctly, for those who are curious:

```
select x.user_id, row_number() over(partition by x.user_id) 
as booking_sequence, x.booking_created_time::date as booking_created_date, x.booking_price_amount, 
sum(y.booking_price_amount) as total_booking_price_amount from 
(
    select user_id, booking_created_time, booking_price_amount from fact_flight_sales 
    group by user_id, booking_created_time, booking_price_amount
) as x
join 
(
    select user_id, booking_price_amount 
    from fact_flight_sales group by user_id, booking_price_amount
) as y
on x.user_id = y.user_id
group by x.user_id, x.booking_created_time, x.booking_price_amount 
having count(x.user_id) >= 1 and sum(y.booking_price_amount) >250000 
order by total_booking_price_amount desc, booking_sequence asc;
```

Big thanks to Laurenz for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### About `count(user_id) > 5`:

`HAVING` is calculated *before* window functions are evaluated, So result rows excluded by the `HAVING` clause will not be used to calculate the window function.

##### About `total_booking_price_amount` in `HAVING`:

You cannot use aliases from the `SELECT` list in the `HAVING` clause. You will have to repeat the expression (or use a subquery).

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by making subqueries and moving the `HAVING` condition on the main query! Thank you. But i don't fully understand what `HAVING` being calculated before window functions mean, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: First the groups are formed and the `SELECT` list items calculated (except the window function calls!). Then the `HAVING` filter is applied. Then the window function is evaluated. So result rows excluded by `HAVING` will not enter into the window function calculation. I thought that's what you were complaining about; the question was a bit unclear here.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not used to describing my thoughts yet!
There were 2 main issues:  
- The code returning 0 rows when I add the count(user_id) > 5 condition, and  
- The total price amount didn't add up because the value in each column was unique and I had to group them using each row.

I fixed the second problem by using subqueries and join to aggregate it separately. Then I fixed the first problem by moving the `HAVING` condition from the first subquery to the main query, but I still don't quite understand why this fixed it, since on the original code it was also on the main query.